# Jquery dialog "cache" variable. How avoid it?

Tags: jquery, select

I have a dialog confirmation that must be reused for several controls in a html page.

Each change in a select, fire this dialog.

This is my code:

```
  console.info("before:" + select[0].id);
  dialog = $('#dialogReject').dialog(
  {
    autoOpen:false,
    height:300,
    width:400,
    modal:true,
    buttons:
    { "Ok":
      function() {
        console.info("after:" + select[0].id);
      },
    } 
  });

  dialog.dialog('open');
```

So, I have 2 selects. I change the first, show the dialog. The `id` in `before` & `after` are equal.

I select the second, change it and show the dialog. Now in `before` the correct `id` is displayed but in `after` is the `id` of the first select.

How avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure I entirely understand the question, but if you are trying to change content in a dialog you will probably need to [.destroy()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-destroy) it after it was called the first time. Let me know if this isn't helpful and hopefully I/someone else can shed some more light on it.

Edit: That wording was vague. What I meant by that was try calling the `.destroy()` method when you close the dialog and you should have no problem with 'caching'.